# How to use particle effects in view based application?

Tags: iphone

How to use **particle effects** in view based application?

I have created a game using view based application and I want to use a particle effects in my game. But, I don't have any idea about using a particle in view based application.

Please give some/any idea.

Answer (score 0):

In generally... you can't. Use fullscreen GL for regular particle effect.

Particle effect requires massive count of sprite drawing and alpha blending. You can do this with GL, however, a GL view cannot be overlay over other UIViews.

Normal UIView is implemented with backing CALayer. This is a kind of GL drawing, but optimized for smooth animation of low density UI, not for massive drawing count. So it's performance is too low and unacceptable for particle effect.

I tested CALayer based particle, and 128 particles were max fps with meaningful fps in 3GS.